# Fit 3D surface with known points in 2D

Tags: 3d, 2d, surface, data-fitting, geometry-surface

What is the best method to infer the 3D locations `Y` of points on a piece of paper that covers an unknown 3D object `f` (e.g. in principle with zero Gaussian curvature), knowing:

- the 2D locations of all dots on the 2D paper (`X`)
- the 3D locations of a subsets of dots (`y` in `Y`, for `f(X)=Y`)?

Is it possible to approximate the a solution if the known 3D locations are not labeled (i.e. when we know the 3D location of some dots, but we don't know which 2D dot they correspond to) by adding a constrain of rigidity (i.e. prefer a minimal deformation of the piece of paper)?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved the problem was to

1. Find the closest rotation `R` and translation `t` displacement that approximates f(X)=Y using SVD. See an example [here](https://github.com/kingjr/ecoggui/blob/master/examples/model_displacement.py) and [here](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671).
2. Fitting a polynomial regression of to solve `R * g(X) + t`, and adding a constrain based on the points local distance. See example [here](https://github.com/kingjr/ecoggui/blob/master/examples/model_surface.py).